# how to implement scratch feature on a touch screen based application

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a feature on touch screen. It is like below:

[image]

so, user can use finger to scratch the grey layer and reveal whether he is a winner.

My questions is, how to achieve this by using Javascript and HTML5?

anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is the basic approach I would take:

1. Draw your scratchie image with the gray background in a HTML5 canvas.
2. Attach event handlers for the `mousedown` and `touchstart` events to set an `isDrawing` flag to true. Conversely, add handlers for `mouseup` and `touchend` to set the flag to false.
3. Attach an event handler for `mousemove` and `touchmove` to check if `isDrawing` and if so, copy a circular part of the image which contains the bit behind the scratchie coating to the position of the cursor/finger.

For the last one, you will need to figure out how to use a masking technique to get the right circular part of the image to draw onto the canvas, with the bits outside the circle transparent.